# Parents method doesn't work for closing Two Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Two Pages that both of them has an image that is used as a Close Button. This is HTML Code :

```
<div id="bioPage">
    <img id="closeBtn" src="Images/CloseButton.png" alt="Close Button" />
</div>
<div id="skillsPage">
    <img id="closeBtn" src="Images/CloseButton.png" alt="Close Button" />
</div>
```

& I want to write a code just once to close pages when the Close Button in them clicked. So I wrote this :

```
$('#closeBtn').click(function() {
    var parentDiv = $(this).parents('div:first');
    parentDiv.css('left', '-100%');
    $('nav').animate({
        'left': '0px'
    }, 500);        
});
```

But It works for the First Page & Second Page doesn't close when the Close Button clicked.

Comment: ID must be unique `id="closeBtn"` you have 2

Comment: ID's must be unique within a html page

Comment: I think he wrote the code of two different html pages `bioPage` and `skillPage` togather, as he explaining he have two pages. So If I am getting correct and the both divs mentioned above are on different pages, the id can be used.

Comment: where you select by id, function return first matched object because in html standard written that id must be unique.

Comment: Oops, I didn't pay attention to that ... Thanks Guys ...

Comment: @vinayofficial No They aren't two HTML Pages ..., It was my mistake in choosing ID ... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. *Identifiers in HTML must be unique.* You can use a common class with the elements then easily use [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

*HTML*

```
<img class="closeBtn" src="Images/CloseButton.png" alt="Close Button" />
```

*Script*

```
$('.closeBtn').click(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$('[id="closeBtn"]').click(function(){
//function here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Id of every element in DOM is suppose to be unique. But here, the "closeBtn" Id is used twice(for both close button element). So you should provide "closeBtn" as class, rather than Id.